Installing nvidia drivers on 24.04 is an impossible task
My expectation is that installing drivers is a ten minute task, max.
My actual result is that it's taken two, three days of work to get no results.
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535-open followed by any form of rebooting my machine means that it loads to a black screen, doesn't reach the desktop. I have to load the machine in safe mode, go to root shell, apt purge ^nvidia.* and then apt install ubuntu-desktop to reset. I expect the same results with other possible drivers.
From there, I tried sudo ubuntu-drivers install. Here's what that gives:
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Loading new nvidia-545.29.06 DKMS files...
Building for 6.8.0-31-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.8.0-31-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-kernel-source-545.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/545.29.06/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-545 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-545 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-545:
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (<= 545.29.06-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (>= 545.29.06); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-545 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu25.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-31-generic
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.39-0ubuntu8.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-545
 nvidia-driver-545
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

edit: pasting my above error message (the whole thing) into google lead me here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-installing-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu/231193/6
At the bottom, the user says the following cmds worked for him
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libnvidia-common-515 libnvidia-gl-515 nvidia-driver-515

so I tried them and it looks like they worked for me too. I'll edit this again if, after more testing, there's still a problem. But initially, rebooting works, nvidia-smi works. Promising stuff

I appear to be having the same problem, also with the 545 driver.  It appear the 545 driver is your preferred driver, as well.    I did not check to see if I got the same error code with the 535 install as it was what was attempted automatically when I upgraded to 24.04, but the install seems to have failed as my system did not load an nvidia driver on boot.

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-550/+question/816151

@amar, thanks but the Ubuntu-supplied drivers also fail for me in 24.04.   I was hoping 545 would address that issue, but apparently it does not.  Perhaps there is some incompatibility between the NVIDIA drivers and the new Ubuntu kernels?

See Installing a mainline Kernel.  After reading that try this handy script.  I believe you need a newer kernel. Try 6.8 starting with the point releases all the way up to 6.9.3 until you find one that works.

I did an apt update today and then installed the server version of 535, rebooted and now my Nvidia drivers are working.   In the system update new versions of the driver were downloaded, so perhaps there was a bug fix.

Try to purge any previous and install 555 via ppa. Follow this simple guide I usually recommend: https://github.com/oddmario/NVIDIA-Ubuntu-Driver-Guide

Why aren't you using the sudo ubuntu-drivers command to install the correct drivers?

@mchid See launchpad bug 2037004 applicable to when this was written. Some database problem (?) prevented ubuntu-drivers from offering the 550 and 555  drivers even when the PPA was used and the 550&555 packages were available via direct install. All fixed now and even the 560 driver is offered.

nvidia-driver-535 is recommended but nvidia-driver-535-open is not. Nvidia usually works with Canonical to make sure the recommended driver installs and works properly. It's recommended to use that instead.

So Basically first I have take backup of both
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
and /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup files to
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.original and /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup.original
and deleted both /etc/X11/xorg.conf and /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup files using

sudo gio trash /etc/X11/xorg.conf


and


sudo gio trash /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup


then through Software and Updates application, I have download metapackage nvidia-driver-535 (proprietary,tested) version of driver and rebooted after that. and it is working correctly. but still hardly some time display is getting flickred.

